# Why I got NaN in this javaScript code?

Tags: javascript, nan

First I test that every variable got a number value:

```
09-11 18:15:00.420:
       d_drop: -1.178791867393647
  drop_at_zero: 0.0731037475605623
   sightHeight: 4.5
    d_distance: 40
     zeroRange: 10

09-11 18:15:00.420:
       d_drop: true
  drop_at_zero: true
   sightHeight: true
    d_distance: true
     zeroRange: true

function isNumber (o) {
  return ! isNaN (o-0) && o != null;
}

 var d_drop; // in calculation this gets value 1.1789

 var d_path = -d_drop - sightHeight + (drop_at_zero + sightHeight) * d_distance / zeroRange;

console.log("Path: " + d_path + " cm");
```

and in the log:

```
09-11 18:15:00.430: D/CordovaLog(1533): Path: NaN cm
```

WHY? I have tried to figure that out couple of hours now and no success, maybe someone has an idea, I haven't!

Thanks!
Sami

-------ANSWER IS that parse every variable when using + operand-----------

var d_path = parseFloat(-d_drop) - parseFloat(sightHeight) + (parseFloat(drop_at_zero) + parseFloat(sightHeight)) * parseFloat(d_distance) / parseFloat(zeroRange);

Comment: One of your variables is *not a number* (`NaN`).

Comment: Where do your variables come from ? If they come from a text input they are taken as text.

Comment: this is not a number: 09-11 18:15:00.420 - it has colons and hyphens

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: @Neurofluxation I assumed this was the logging traces

Comment: ah I see - that makes sense - can you format your answer so its clearer?

Comment: Which of those two sets of numbers are you actually using? The second "all true" set would produce a NaN result.

Comment: @MarcB: I assume that there's only one set of numbers: the first log-entry prints the values, and the second one prints the results of some boolean test to confirm they're numeric.

Comment: Ah, so we meet again, the dark side of JS `+` operator...

Comment: @Ruakh you are right, just that it is. Sorry guys that my code was not clear and thanks to that person how make it clear :) I was too bussy when I made this and now I am back in business. I am not using -d_drop as a variable name but d_drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The addition operator `+` will cast things as strings if either operand is a string. You need to parse ALL of your inputs (`d_drop`, `sightHeight`, etc) as numbers before working with them.

Here's a demo of how the `+` overload works. Notice how the subtraction operator `-` is not overloaded and will always cast the operands to numbers:

```
var numberA = 1;
var numberB = 2;
var stringA = '3';
var stringB = '4';

numberA + numberB // 3 (number)
numberA - numberB // -1 (number)
stringA + stringB // "34" (string)
stringA - stringB // -1 (number)
numberA + stringB // "14" (string)
numberA - stringB // -3 (number)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/abwhd/

Comment: Thanks a lot @jabey and Kolink. Which one of you were the first one who answered this? You made my day!

Comment: @Sami i believe i answered first, but Kolink's answer looks better to me.

Comment: I think that you deserve the answer mark then? Though I dont't get this why this is working like that? I checked carefully before calculation that every variable is not string, they are number, but something is happening when using + operand? If it is so, his answer is little bit more precise.

Comment: @Sami when you print a variable to a console or other visual output, it is automatically converted to a string representation, so there's really no way to tell (without a `typeof` check) which was a string and which was a number.

Comment: ok, thanks! I hate JS now. So I think that you deserve the answer mark, because you were the first :)

Comment: @Sami i've added some examples

Comment: But if my isNumber function is working correctly, every variable should have been numbers. Before the + operand I checked with isNumber-function that every variable is number, not string. I added the function to my question.

Answer (score 3):

At least one of your numbers is a string. `sightHeight` is the most likely culprit, as it would concatenate with `drop_at_zero` to produce a "number" with two decimal points - such a "number" is not a number, hence `NaN`.

Solution: use `parseFloat(varname)` to convert to numbers.

Comment: var d_path = parseFloat(-d_drop) - parseFloat(sightHeight) + (parseFloat(drop_at_zero) + parseFloat(sightHeight)) * parseFloat(d_distance) / parseFloat(zeroRange); I still not get it why my function is returning true but some variable is not a number? Your concatenate solution sounds right, but this is really annoying :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `-d_drop` as a variable name, that is probably the culprit. Variables must start with a letter.

```
var     d_drop = -1.178791867393647,
  drop_at_zero = 0.0731037475605623,
   sightHeight = 4.5,
    d_distance = 40,
     zeroRange = 10;

var d_path = d_drop - sightHeight + (drop_at_zero + sightHeight) * d_distance / zeroRange;

console.log("Path: " + d_path + " cm"); // outputs: Path: 12.613623122848603 cm
```

Comment: No I am not using -d_drop as a variable but d_drop: var d_drop